# How to identify whether user entered search text or a website?

Tags: android, url, android-webview

So I am building an floating application that would allow user to browse webpages and allow them to listen audio from video sites like YouTube, etc. even when the device is locked/in background.

Here I have a text box where user can input the websites or any text that they want to search *i.e. SomeSite.com, www.SomeSite.com, Some Text To Be Search*

I want to know is there any efficient way to do this. Currently I am thinking differentiating this by counting space in text (if there is 1 or more space then text is definitely not URL). But this won’t work for 1 word search query. Also another way is to check for top level domain like .com, .in, .uk, etc. not good as there could be thousands of domains and in future also it could increase.

I just want a effective to differentiate site or an web address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Patterns](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#WEB_URL) class available from API level 8.

```
if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(myUrl).matches()) {
    // Go to website
} else {
    // Submit as search query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- [isValidRul()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl(java.lang.String))
- [Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html#WEB_URL)
- Check if [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) returns valid value